# java+ ConcurrentModificationException forEach(enhanced) loop single thread

Tags: java, collections

I am not able to understand the reason, why the below code is throwing CME, even when this is run as single thread application

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ConcurrentModification {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConcurrentModification con = new ConcurrentModification();
        con.call();
    }

    void call() {
        List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10000; i++) {
            l.add(i);
        }

            for (Integer j : l) {
                if (j % 3 == 0) {
                    l.remove(j);
                }
            }


    }
}
```

**Reason:**(after going through the answer and other links)

```
You are not permitted to mutate a list while you are iterating over it.   
Only Iterator remove's method can be used to delete element from list  
For Each loop is using iterator beneath it  
but l.remove(j) is not using that iterator, which causes the exception
```

Comment: You're removing an item from a list while you're iterating over it, but not performing the removal using `Iterator.remove`. There are lots of duplicates of this - I'll try to find one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not permitted to mutate a list while you are iterating over it. Your `l.remove(j)` causes the list `l` to change, but you're inside a `for (Integer j : l)` loop.

Comment: one question, is not the for each loop is using iterator beneath it

Comment: @Naroji: Yes, but the `l.remove(j)` is not using that iterator, which causes the exception you observed.

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to use iterator

```
 for (Iterator<ProfileModel> it = params[0].iterator(); it
                        .hasNext();) {

                    ProfileModel model = it.next();

                    DBModel.addProfile(homeScreenActivity, model, profileId);
                }
```

I used it to add data in database..Hope it helps