# Skipping a particular value of ArrayList during printing

Tags: java, arraylist

My Code is as follows:

```
ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList();
al.add(1);
al.add(2);
al.add(3);
al.add(3);
al.add(4);
```

I want the following pattern during printing:

```
[1,2,4]
```

I tried both for loop and Iterator but I am not getting the desired output.

Help me to sort out!

I found the solution and that is

```
for(int i=0;i<al.size();i++) {
if(al.get(i)!=3) 
   System.out.println(al.get(i));
  }
```

thanks for your help

Now I want to get the same output, not through printing but by deleting elements of ArrayList, I tried with the same condition but I got exception

and the answer is

```
Iterator<Integer> iter = al.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            if (iter.next().intValue() == 3) {
                iter.remove();
            }
        }
        System.out.println(al);
```

Comment: This seems simple enough but what issue are you having? What output are you getting and what's wrong with it?

Comment: post the code you have tried please so we can see what you are doing wrong

Comment: You want to skip duplicates? you should describe the relationship between values in List and out put.

Comment: See... If you dont tell us exactly what you want, you will get all sort of answers based on every individual's understanding...

Comment: Is your pattern about power of 2s?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Step through all the items in the `ArrayList` and test if they are equal to `3`, if they are not, print them.

```
for (Integer i : al)  //for each Integer in the al list
{
  if (!i.equals(3))  //if it is NOT (!) equal to 3
  {
    System.out.println(i);  //then print it
  }
}
```

Obviously if you want to skip more than just the number 3 you will need to expand the condition the `if` uses.

**Note on removing elements from the list**

If you try and remove from the list within the loop using this method you will encounter problems with `ConcurrentAccessException`, this is dealt with in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/efficient-equivalent-for-removing-elements-while-iterating-the-collection).

Comment: Now I want to get the same output, not through printing but by deleting elements of ArrayList, I tried with the same condition but I got exception

Comment: You need to provide more info but most likely a `ConcurrentAccessException` if you are trying to delete items in a for each loop.  This means using the normal `for` loop i.e. `for (x;y;z)` or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547584/java-concurrentmodificationexception-foreachenhanced-loop-single-thread

Comment: Good, I've expanded my answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the list element and as per your output it seems you want to print 1 and  even numbers in the list

```
for(int i=0; i< a1.size(); i++)  //iterate over List
{
    if(a1.get(i)%2=0 || a1.get(i) == 1) //print if 1 or even
      System.out.println(a1.get(i));
}
```

Comment: the number 1 is even?

Comment: " it seems you want to print even number in the list" .. Quite frankly, he isn't telling what exactly he wants... Not your mistake.. :)

Comment: "it seems you want to print even number in the list" this would be incorrect if OP wants to print `1` no?

Comment: I didn't mention it in the first statement but it is there in the code and comment

Comment: you are assuming too much.. The OP needs to specify the logic for not printing elements..

Comment: This is not wrong... And I dont know if its right.. There must be logic behind this... and you are assuming it to be 1 or even number...

Comment: All the answers for this post are assumption based, you might be thinking same for all the answers. @TheLostMind

Comment: Hi all, I want slight modification in my program, this time I want to delete a particular value in the ArrayList, is it possible to alter the same arrylist or I have to create a new one???

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `forEach` method (Java 8):

```
al.forEach(v -> {if(v!=3) System.out.println(v);});
```

Answer (score 0):

add the required skipping values in a list and check against that list before printing

My code:run and give comment(views please)

```
import java.util.*;
public class Mycode{

 public static void main(String []args){
     ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList();
al.add(1);
al.add(2);
al.add(3);
al.add(3);
al.add(4);

      ArrayList<Integer> al1 = new ArrayList();
      al1.add(3);
      al1.add(2);
      int flag=0;
      for(int j=0; j< al.size(); j++)
      {
          flag=0;
      for(int i=0; i< al1.size(); i++)
      {
      if(al.get(j)==al1.get(i))
      flag=1;
      }
        if(flag==0)
      System.out.println(al.get(j));
      }
 }
}
```